# slickgrid set edit mode on row

Tags: slickgrid

I am using slick grid on a page, when I select a row I would like the entire row to enter edit mode.

For example I have an checkbox in one column and a input field for text in another and a non-editable field in another, when I click on anywhere on the row I want the checkbox and input field to be displayed to the user.